# put a time limit on the program

Tags: time, limit, trial

Kindly advise on below requirement

We need to include a trial period or a time limit to a program. We have only the exe file. We do not have the source files. Is there any tool available to include a trial period (like limiting 30 days) to this exe file

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a bunch of such protector-applications, for example:

Enigma - http://enigmaprotector.com/
WinLicense - http://www.oreans.com/winlicense.php
VMProtect - http://vmpsoft.com/

and others

Answer (score 0):

You could create an own exe-file which calls your trial-exe (which you should rename to something like `.lib`). After 30 days your exe deletes the trial-exe. But if the users gets behind this it will fail ;-)

Hmm, you can secure this a little by encrypting the trial-exe and decrypting it on runtime. It your be ideal if the decrypted file would not resist in a temp file but only in memory.